# Checking whether a minecraft account is a part of MCleaks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am looking for a program/ piece of code that I can implement to prove that a Minecraft uuid is being used by MCLeaks (the service for free Minecraft alts). I've found some server plugins on the web, but I didn't come across any implementable pieces of code that I can use to check whether a given uuid is a part of MCleaks or not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why would you doubt whether a version is legal (which I assume is your goal)?

Comment: Free account services are often used by cheaters to avoid bans.

Answer (score 1):

This api will let you do just that: https://github.com/TheMrGong/MCLeaksApiClient

You can check if a UUID is part of MCLeaks using this code:

```
MCLeaksAPI api = MCLeaksAPI.builder()
                .threadCount(2)
                .expireAfter(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
if(api.checkAccount(uuid).isMCLeaks()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```